# Trigger automatically gets disabled... why?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a trigger that keeps getting disabled. It will run from months at time without issue then just be disabled. Why?

It would be cool to know:
Is there a way I can log when it get's disabled?
What is disabling it?
Is there a way to set up an email alert that it has been disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has to be disabling it.  You can setup a SQL trace that runs in the background looking for the ALTER TRIGGER command.

If you were using SQL Server 2005 and above you could put a DDL trigger on the database to rollback the ALTER statement, then log the command.

With SQL 2000 about all you've got available to you is running a trace.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 has DDL triggers too... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191441(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Humm, not sure why I thought those were introduced in SQL 2008. To many damn versions out there.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what other people may have their fingers in your database... another possibility is that someone has a job or stored procedure or a piece of code that is:

```
Disabling the trigger 
Performing an action 
Enabling the trigger 
(however it fails somewhere before the enable)
```

-or-

```
Disabling the trigger
Performing an action
NOT enabling the trigger
```

You may want to do a quick search through your code and sprocs/jobs for the name of your trigger to see if someone is doing something like this.